# Why memset of array of structure changing the program behaviour?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof, memset

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PIPE "myPipeName"

typedef enum 
{
    ID1,
    ID2
}TEST_ID;

typedef struct
{
    double dCnt;
    TEST_ID id ;
}Response;

int main()
{
    char pipeName[256]=PIPE;
    Response res[2];
    printf("1. pipeName : %s , PIPE : %s\n",pipeName,PIPE);
    memset(res,0,2*sizeof(res));
    printf("2. pipeName : %s , PIPE : %s\n",pipeName,PIPE);

    return 0;
}
```

Actual o/p:

> 1. pipeName : myPipeName , PIPE :myPipeName
> 2. pipeName :  , PIPE : myPipeName

Expected o/p:

> 1. pipeName : myPipeName , PIPE :myPipeName
> 2. pipeName : myPipeName , PIPE :myPipeName

Please let me know how can I solve this ?

Comment: `2*sizeof(res)`...hmmm..

Comment: Thanks . Today I lost my common sense it seems .. But I don't know why you guys down vote .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running out of bound there, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Change

```
 memset(res,0,2*sizeof(res));
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
memset(res,0,sizeof(res));
```

or, if you prefer the *multiplied* version (*for better readability, maybe?*), use

```
memset( res , 0 , 2 * sizeof(res[0]));
```

or

```
memset( res , 0 , 2 * sizeof(Response));
```

That said, uninitialized automatic variable value is indeterministic. **Don't** try to use them.

Comment: multiplied version is not a good idea. We have to maintain it if the dimension of `res` changed.

Comment: @songyuanyao That is why that's a _second_ choice, but nevertheless, it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response res[2];//is an array of 2 Responses

sizeof(res);//get the size of the array in bytes

memset(res,0,2*sizeof(res));//the multiplication by the size of the array is not needed here and 
                            //the memset is writing 0 out of bound of the array and probably
                            //into pipeName which would be treated as null terminator character
```

Writing out of the array bound is undefined behavior, so change to:

```
memset(res,0,sizeof(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a wrong size value

```
memset(res,0,2*sizeof(res));
```

Should be

```
memset(res,0,sizeof(res));
```

Because of `sizeof(res)` return the **size of array in bytes.**

Or

```
memset(res,0,2*sizeof(Response));
```

Because of `sizeof(Response)` return the **size of the Response typedef struct in bytes.**